# Stopping times convergence

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stopping-times

I have this problem.

Let $X_t$ be a continuous, adapted stochastic process. We define this sequence of stopping times
$$
s_n(\omega) = T \land inf\{t\in[0,T]| |X_t(\omega)|\ge n\}
$$ 
In my book is written that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n(\omega) = T a.s 
$$

I can't understand that almost surely. I can't figure out a trajectory in which that sequence does not converge increasingly.

Take into account that $inf\{\emptyset \}= \infty$ so that, eventually, $s_n(\omega)=T$.

Thanks !

Comment: It comes down to technicalities about the definition of $X_t$. In principle $X_t$ could blow up in finite time but regardless of how $X_t$ was defined, the continuity relegates this to a probability zero event. As an example, some constructions of Brownian motion exhibit this kind of finite time blowup.

Comment: Let's say that $X_t$ blow up in finite time. How can you say this event as zero probability?

Comment: Also just in general, don't fret over a.s. and a.e. qualifiers on statements. Most of the time they do not really matter much.

Comment: It is part of the definition of continuous process: a trajectory is continuous with probability 1.

Comment: in my book, we say that a trajectory is a.s continuous :) if is continuous with probability equal to one

Comment: \*shrug\* Again these kinds of things can be dodged by adjusting definitions but it can be annoying to do so. For example you can define a continuous process as a measure on $C([0,T])$ instead, in which case trajectories are surely continuous by definition. But then a lot of the way we like to think about things (like the "broken line" construction of BM) is not rigorously correct. It is easier to just put a.s. all over the place in stochastic process theory.

Answer (score 0):

If $\omega$ is a sample point such that $[0,T]\ni t\mapsto X_t(\omega)\in\Bbb R$ is continuous, then $\lim_ns_n(\omega) =T$. In fact, there exists $n_0(\omega)$ such that $s_n(\omega) =T$ for all $n\ge n_0(\omega)$.